# .htaccess redirecting without main page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to redirect my site from www to a non-www, but without "main page".

Eg. www.domain.com or www.domain.com/ do nothing, but www.domain.com/everything-else should redirect to domain.com/everything-else

Why the code below redirect also "main page"?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps because you also allow *empty* url requests by doing `^(.*)$` in the `RewriteRule`.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

`.*` accepts any charachter zero or more times while `.+` would accept any character one or more times.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this; `http://localhost/ (index.php says $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is /)`

I think, even while showing the root of a site "REQUEST_URI" can not be empty, it would be "/". So maybe you should try something like this;

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn`t that working?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=307,NC,L]
```